# Laravel API Architecture - best practices

Tags: php, laravel, api-design

I'm implementing an API that can create clients and create contacts. Contacts may be associated with a client.

I have my ClientController.php with all the CRUD methods.

I also have a ContactController.php with all the CRUD methods.

I want to allow a contact to be created and assigned to a client all in the one API call.

I was thinking the best way would be add a function to my ClientController and call it via the API: **/api/client/6/addContact**

```
public function addContact($clientId, Request $request) {
   $contact = new Contact($request->all())->save();

   $client = Client::find($clientId)->attach($contact->id);

   return response()->json(null, 200);

}
```

But my issue is that the method to add a contact (and validate it) is in the ContactController.php, so i'm doubling up on the code. How can I use the ContactController@store method from the ClientController@addContact ?

Is there a common API architecture for these types of issues?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a service pattern. In a project I'm working on right now, I make plain PHP classes in an `App\Services` namespace that I can then inject into my controllers (or other services) to provide functionality, passing in any required HTTP data like get/post variables to the service.

Comment: @Nathan maybe he should use eloquent observers. he is not trying to use a third party library.Ben Southall, if you use Laravel 5.3 or plus, you should use observers because you are observing add client method. for more info read this please : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#observers

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih thanks for this, i read about observers many times but never thought i could use it to achieve this

Comment: so as i understood you have a `client` that is saved, now you want to create a `contact` and attach it to a `client`, if so why don't you just call `$client->contacts()->attach($contact->id)`  in the store method of `ContactController` ?

Comment: Thanks @Nathan could you give me an example of your service? I can seem to find this pattern anywhere in the laravel docs.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a nested [api resource route](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes):

```
// generate the controller class
php artisan make:controller Api/ContactController --api

// create the route definitions
Route::apiResource('clients.contacts', 'ContactController');
```

The above creates the routes:

```
GET /clients/{client}/contacts
POST /clients/{client}/contacts
GET /clients/{client}/contacts/{contact}
PUT/PATCH /clients/{client}/contacts/{contact}
DELETE /clients/{client}/contacts/{contact}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a one to many relationship. I would focus on establishing that relationship in eloquent and then the rest will fall into place:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

After you create the relationship correctly your API calls will be structured around a json string (object) that will have one client and one or more contacts.

If you have any questions, please ask, but this basic strategy will get you to where you want to go.